# GVR Audio Spatializer plugin missing in Unity

Tags: google-vr

[image: Missing GVR Audio Spacializer]

I can't seem to figure out how to get the Unity Audio Manager to see the GVR Audio Spacializer.

I have had the SDK installed and everything works by the GVR Audiosource stuff.

SDK seems to be missing parts of the library:

```
DllNotFoundException: audioplugingvrunity
```

GvrAudio.Initialize (.GvrAudioListener listener, Quality quality) (at Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Audio/GvrAudio.cs:73)
GvrAudioListener.Awake () (at Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Audio/GvrAudioListener.cs:38)

I'm on a mac, not sure why it's looking for a DLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure building for Android and have imported *all* the GVR audio bits (including x86).

OP also asked on forum and a Google employee answered then OP resolved (posting answer + notes here for any others that find this question first like I did):

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/gvr-audio-spatializer-plugin-missing-in-unity.446017/